# Entity Framework: "The member in the conceptual model is not present in the OSpace"

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA Services July CTP in a Silverlight app and when I change the name of a navigation property I get the following error:

Error   119 The Member 'TestUsers' in the conceptual model type 'MyModel.UserGroup' is not present in the OSpace  type 'MyApp.Web.UserGroup'.

Is there an extra step when changing the name to a navigation property?

Comment: I got a crazy EF model that covers an entire huge DB. It is impossible to use "Update from DB" and so on. So, all guys use a manual updating for `.edmx` and `.designer.cs` - crazy EF stuff. Just got the same error when I merged commits for `.edmx` XML file and lost commits for `.Designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well when you say you changed the name of a navigation property, do mean you changed it in the EF model Designer / EDMX file? Or just in the CLR?

You need to change it in both places.

Hope it is just this simple,

Alex James

Comment: For some reason, when I removed a property and added it in the designer, then ran update DB from model, the XMl didn't change and I got this error. So I opened it up and viewed as xml and made the change manually, then it worked.